# 'Startup' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

New to Asp.Net Core 2.0 and following https://medium.com/@lugrugzo/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8 article to get Mysql JWT based authentication done.

Getting this error when trying to run the project:

In Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

I get this error:

```
error CS0119: 'Startup' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

and the Startup class after adding some blocks to something like this:
In Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ===== Add our DbContext ========
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

        // ===== Add Identity ========
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                };
            });

        // ===== Add MVC ========
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext
    )
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // ===== Use Authentication ======
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();

        // ===== Create tables ======
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Both the files; Program.cs and Startup.cs belong to same namespace.

I am unable to figure out exactly what code block is creating the problem. I think these errors are supposed to come often. So, please also let me know if there is a way to detect it.

Comment: Either you have two types called Startup (i.e. maybe a struct and a class) or you are trying to use a namespace as generic type. Importing the correct namespace where your startup class is located or using the full qualifed name should work though

Comment: Can you just download the repo and build it? I guess you have two startup files but I'm not sure.

Comment: @OzgurGUL I downloaded the repository and run, got the same error.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I was unable to get any error.

Comment: @OzgurGUL Is there anything to be done for npm like mentioned in this post: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/issues/344

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: @OzgurGUL It is not working on Mac but on windows it is working but again unable to generate tables out of it.

Comment: Did you create the database named `webapijwt`. Edit `ApplicationDbContext` file please. Also, `npm` is not necessary.

Comment: @OzgurGUL Instead, I changed connectionstring to my online database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
but when i commented that line i found an strange character there
once i removed it and un-commented the line everything was fine.
Character was exactly before WordEntities.(i have attached image)

```
//identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ٌWordEntities>()
//.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpqQm.jpg)